# How to convert cube root of this equation into TeX?

Tags: text

When I solve the equation $$\sqrt[3]{-3 x+6}+\sqrt[3]{2
   x+4}+\sqrt[3]{x-10}=0$$
I used

```
Reduce[Root[#^3 - (-3 x + 6) &, 1] + Root[#^3 - (2 x + 4) &, 1] + Root[#^3 - ( x - 10) &, 1] == 0, x, Reals]
```

> x == -2 || x == 2 || x == 10

Now, I want to use `TeXForm[HoldForm]]`

```
TeXForm[Root[#^3 - (-3 x + 6) &, 1] + Root[#^3 - (2 x + 4) &, 1] + Root[#^3 - ( x - 10) &, 1] == 0]
```

I want to receive
`\sqrt[3]{-3 x+6}+\sqrt[3]{2x+4}+\sqrt[3]{x-10}=0` and then, I must do

```
TeXForm[HoldForm[Power[-3 x + 6, (3)^-1] + Power[2 x + 4, (3)^-1] + Power[x - 10, (
    3)^-1] == 0]]
```

How can I convert directly from

```
TeXForm[Root[#^3 - (-3 x + 6) &, 1] + Root[#^3 - (2 x + 4) &, 1] + Root[#^3 - ( x - 10) &, 1] == 0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're seeking?

```
TeXForm[CubeRoot[-3 x + 6] + CubeRoot[2 x + 4] + CubeRoot[x - 10] == 0]
```

$
\sqrt[3]{6-3 x}+\sqrt[3]{x-10}+\sqrt[3]{2x+4}=0
$

You are taking roots of the three *individual* terms in the equation, but you should instead take the root of the *full* equation.  Also note how to take a `CubeRoot` in *Mathematica* (not the way you were).

The solutions are

```
mysols = Solve[CubeRoot[-3 x + 6] + CubeRoot[2 x + 4] + CubeRoot[x - 10] == 0, x]
```

(*
{{x -> -2}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 10}}
*)

as can be tested:

```
CubeRoot[-3 x + 6] + CubeRoot[2 x + 4] + CubeRoot[x - 10] == 0 /. x -> 2
```

(* TRUE *)

```
CubeRoot[-3 x + 6] + CubeRoot[2 x + 4] + CubeRoot[x - 10] == 0 /. x -> -2
```

(* TRUE *)

```
CubeRoot[-3 x + 6] + CubeRoot[2 x + 4] + CubeRoot[x - 10] == 0 /. x -> 10
```

(* TRUE *)

These can be seen when you plot the function:

```
g[x_] := CubeRoot[-3 x + 6] + CubeRoot[2 x + 4] + CubeRoot[x - 10];
Plot[g[x], {x, -5, 11},
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, y], Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an extended comment.

```
f[x_] = (6 - 3 x)^(1/3) + (2 x + 4)^(1/3) + (x - 10)^(1/3);
```

None of the proposed solutions satisfy the equation `f[x] == 0`

```
f /@ {-2, 2, 10} // Simplify
```

> {2^(2/3)*3^(1/3)*(1 + (-1)^(1/3)),     2*(1 + (-1)^(1/3)),
>   2*((-3)^(1/3) + 3^(1/3))}

```
% // N
```

> {3.43414 + 1.9827 I, 3. + 1.73205 I, 4.32675 + 2.49805 I}

To see that there is no solution

```
Solve[f[x] == 0, x]
```

> {}

```
Reduce[f[x] == 0, x]
```

> False

```
NSolve[f[x] == 0, x]
```

> {}

```
NMinimize[{Abs[f[x]], -3 <= x <= 11}, x]
```

> {3.46542, {x -> 2.}}

```
Plot[{Re[f[x]], Im[f[x]], Abs[f[x]]},
 {x, -3, 11}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]